# Second order signature operator in diffeomorphism invariant geometry as an image under right regular representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, operator-theory, noncommutative-geometry, differential-operators

I would like to understand the following statement taken from [this](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/transverse.pdf) paper, dealing with the so called Transverse Index Theory or in other words with the index theory for diffeomorphism invariant geometry. The authors construct *second order* signature operator $Q$ being a part of spectral triple which encodes the diffeomorphism invariant geometry of a given manifold. The task is to compute the Chern character of the corresponding spectral triple. Here is the statement which I would like to understand:

> The operator $Q$ is in fact the image under the right regular representation of the affine group $G_1$ (which is the semidirect product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $GL^+(n,\mathbb{R})$ ) of a (matrix valued) hypoelliptic symmetric element in $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1)$

(here $\mathfrak{g}_1$ is the Lie algebra of $G_1$ and $\mathcal{U}$ stands for universal enveloping algebra). In [another](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0505475.pdf) paper dealing with the same topic there is a similar statement which reads as follows:

> Note that $Q$ is affiliated with the universal enveloping algebra of the group of affine motions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the sense that it is of the form 
>   $Q=R(Q_{{alg}})$ with 
>   $$Q_{alg} \in \Big(\mathfrak{A}\big(\mathbb{R}^n \rtimes \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})\big) \otimes End(E) \Big)^{SO(n)}$$
>   where $R$ is right regular representation of $\mathbb{R}^n \rtimes GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $E$ is unitary $SO(n)$-module.

(here I suspect that $\mathfrak{A}$ should mean teh same as $\mathcal{U}$ above). 
I would like to understand it in detail, where each term lives, how the right regular representation is understood here, how $E$ is defined etc. As it is written it is complete mystery for me.